# Create Folder and Update Title and Custom Field in Sharepoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online

I try to create folder in sharepoint online, based on some of tutorial. the problem comes since creating folder is not given "Title" column value.

I want to create folder and also update column "Title".

here is the code for create folder

```
public string CreateDocumentLibrary(string siteUrl, string relativePath)
    {
        //bool responseResult = false;
        string resultUpdate = string.Empty;
        string responseResult = string.Empty;
        if (siteUrl != _siteUrl)
        {
            _siteUrl = siteUrl;
            Uri spSite = new Uri(siteUrl);

            _spo = SpoAuthUtility.Create(spSite, _username, WebUtility.HtmlEncode(_password), false);
        }

        string odataQuery = "_api/web/folders";

        byte[] content = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(@"{ '__metadata': { 'type': 'SP.Folder' }, 'ServerRelativeUrl': '" + relativePath + "'}");

        string digest = _spo.GetRequestDigest();

        Uri url = new Uri(String.Format("{0}/{1}", _spo.SiteUrl, odataQuery));
        // Set X-RequestDigest
        var webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(url);
        webRequest.Headers.Add("X-RequestDigest", digest);

        // Send a json odata request to SPO rest services to fetch all list items for the list.
        byte[] result = HttpHelper.SendODataJsonRequest(
          url,
          "POST", // reading data from SP through the rest api usually uses the GET verb 
          content,
          webRequest,
          _spo // pass in the helper object that allows us to make authenticated calls to SPO rest services
          );

        string response = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(result, 0, result.Length);

        if (response != null)
        {
            //responseResult = true;
            responseResult = response;
        }
        return responseResult;
    }
```

I already tried to use CAML, but, the problem is, the list of sharepoint is big, so got the error prohibited access related to limit tresshold.

Please help.

Answer (score 1):

Refer below code to update folder name.

```
function renameFolder(webUrl,listTitle,itemId,name)
{
     var itemUrl =  webUrl + "/_api/Web/Lists/GetByTitle('" + listTitle + "')/Items(" + itemId + ")";
     var itemPayload = {};
     itemPayload['__metadata'] = {'type': getItemTypeForListName(listTitle)};
     itemPayload['Title'] = name;
     itemPayload['FileLeafRef'] = name;
     var additionalHeaders = {};
     additionalHeaders["X-HTTP-Method"] = "MERGE";
     additionalHeaders["If-Match"] =  "*";
     return executeJson(itemUrl,"POST",additionalHeaders,itemPayload);
}


function getItemTypeForListName(name) {
   return"SP.Data." + name.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + name.slice(1) + "ListItem";
}
```

Comment: How to get ItemID?